# Quarantining kernel-level games onto a VM

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine, vmware, privacy

Let's say I have drive running Linux and a partition of that storing a VM containing a game like Valorant using. Is there a way for processes within the VM to break through the virtualization layer given ring0 access to the VM?

And because Valorant detects it's in a VM because of virtualization processes, is there a way to hide those things from even kernel-level stuff and to trick it into thinking it's running on native windows 10?

I saw this post on reddit that works for BattlEye games:
https://www.reddit.com/r/VFIO/comments/i071qx/spoof_and_make_your_vm_undetectable_no_more/

Would this work for Riot Vanguard-based games, like Valorant or LoL? And if so, would it be detectable to processes running inside the VM, or would it just look like a native OS?

I would just do dual-boot if it weren't for the fact that there's no fast way to hotswap between OS's...

Comment: Questions about circumventing terms of service are usually frowned upon here.

Comment: Even if Valorant could not detect it was a VM there is no way the hypervisor could meet the requirements required to run Valorant as there are zero hypervisors that support DX12 and Vulkan

Comment: If it is possible, I highly recommend you to stop playing games with such intrusive components. I stopped playing League of Legends IMMEDIATELY after Riot announced Vanguard would be used on it. The more people care, the more possibility such things will not happen in the future.